# Broadcast Receiver Registration

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am new to android.
            My project is having one activity and one service. My service is having one broadcast receiver and activity is having broadcast sender which is in PeriodSender method  .Dynamically when i am registering the receiver then at the start of the service it is not invoking but if i send some thing after few moment then it invokes.
            But I want to register it in Manifest ,I have included the receiver details in Manifest but the receiver is not invoking . My receiver class name is MyReceiver21 and the intent action is MY_ACTION1.  actually I want my broadcast receiver to be registered at the starting it self.

```
Following is my Manifest file





        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.experiment.Test"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >
            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="3"
                android:targetSdkVersion="3" />
            <application
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name="com.experiment.Test.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver21" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.experiment.Test.MainActivity.MY_ACTION1" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service
                    android:name="Myservice21"
                    android:enabled="true" />

            </application>
        </manifest>


    my activity code is









    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
        MediaPlayer OurSong;
        Context SavedThis=this;
        int i=0;
        public  Handler handler1 = new Handler();   
        public  Handler handler2= new Handler();
        Button Start;
        Button Stop;

        Button Button21;


        Button StopButton;
        public int GProgreess=0;
        int Rc=0;
        int BitCount=0;
        int SeekPos=0;
        int Period=500;
        MyReceiver myReceiver;
        final static String MY_ACTION1 = "MY_ACTION1";

        public int  Data=0;
        public int  beat=0;

        int BreakVar=0;
        Thread myThread ;
        static public TextView text1,text2,text3,text4;
        private SeekBar bar;
        private TextView textProgress,textAction;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




            StopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);





            StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {           


                    stopService(new Intent(SavedThis,Myservice21.class));


                    BitCount=0;

                }/****End of on clk******/

            });/*****End of set on clk listener*****/

            Button21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {                       

                    Rc=0;
                    BitCount=13;

                    stopService(new Intent(SavedThis,Myservice25.class));
                    SystemClock.sleep(200);     

                    startService(new Intent(SavedThis,Myservice21.class));      




                    PeriodSender();
                }/****End of on clk******/

            });/*****End of set on clk listener*****/




        }










        public void PeriodSender()
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent();
            intent1.setAction("MY_ACTION1");
            intent1.putExtra("kz", Period);
            sendBroadcast(intent1); 
            text3.setText(""+Period);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PeriodSent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }






        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }



my service class











public class Myservice21 extends Service {

     int BitCount=0;
     int Rc=0;

     int   Period=500;

     Intent intent = new Intent();  
     MyReceiver21 myReceiver21;
     public  Handler handler1 = new Handler();  

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public void onCreate()
    {


        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);    


        myReceiver21 = new MyReceiver21();
         IntentFilter intentFilter1 = new IntentFilter();
         intentFilter1.addAction(com.experiment.Test.MainActivity.MY_ACTION1);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver21, intentFilter1);       
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Myservice21.this,MainActivity.class);
         startService(intent1);

        handler1.post(runnable1);
    }


public class MyReceiver21 extends BroadcastReceiver {

           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
           {
               int data = intent.getIntExtra("kz", 0); 
               Period=data;
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PeriodRceived21",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }

        }



    public void onStart(Intent intent,int StartId)
    {
        Rc=0;


    }


    public void onDestroy()
    {



    }







}

        can any one help me to register the receiver in manifest. Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the intent filter for your own broadcasts. Just register the service for that broadcasts with `registerReceiver()` when the service is started.

Note, that you have to start the service manually when your App starts, for instance in the `MainActivity.onCreate():`

```
startService(new Intent(this, Myservice21.class));
```

When the MainActivity has been created, it will start the service, which itself registers for BroadcastIntents and starts listening for them. This should work.